# yahoo pipes How can i swap title and description

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I was creating a RSS feed using yahoo pipes but i want title in description and description in title. I want to swap the title and description.

```
<item>
<title>"**title**"</title>
<description>"**description**"</description>
<link>http://link</link>
</item>
```

I want

```
<item>
<title>"**description**"</title>
<description>"**title**"</description>
<link>http://link</link>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it - using 3 Pipes modules to swap the title and description fields:

1. Fetch Feed: Pull in the RSS feed. I'm using a [Yahoo Finance feed](http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topfinstories) as a sample.
2. Rename: Make a copy of item.title as newDesc, and item.description as newTitle
3. Create RSS: Set title to newTitle, description to newDesc, others as default values

I created a sample pipe you can view and copy from: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ffc846056c71a4dd3df7b01d16fdd613

Here's a sample from the original [Yahoo Finance RSS feed](http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topfinstories):

```
<item>
    <title>Samsung Posts $7.4B Profit as Handsets Mask Weak Chip Sales</title>
    <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/SIG=149kpevtc/*http%3A//us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/topfinstories/SIG=126hhlj6u/*http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-posts-7-4-bln-234859667.html?l=1</link>
    <description>Samsung Electronics Co., the world's top technology firm by revenue, reported record quarterly profit of $7.4 billion on Friday, with strong sales of its Galaxy range of phones masking sharply lower memory chip sales.</description>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo_finance/1866191516</guid>
    <pubDate>Fri, 26 Oct 12 00:55:44 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

...and here's the corresponding output from the sample pipe, with title & description swapped:

```
<item>
     <title>Samsung Electronics Co., the world's top technology firm by revenue, reported record quarterly profit of $7.4 billion on Friday, with strong sales of its Galaxy range of phones masking sharply lower memory chip sales.</title>
     <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/SIG=149kpevtc/*http%3A//us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/topfinstories/SIG=126hhlj6u/*http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/news/samsung-posts-7-4-bln-234859667.html?l=1</link>
     <description>Samsung Posts $7.4B Profit as Handsets Mask Weak Chip Sales</description>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo_finance/1866191516</guid>
     <pubDate>Sat, 30 Mar 1918 19:36:14 +0000</pubDate>
  </item>
```

Note: in my sample above something happened to the pubDate. I think it might be a Yahoo Pipes caching issue that will clear up the next time the pipe runs.